# Easiest way to write to/ read from raw NAND flash memory?

Tags: embedded, filesystems, microcontroller, flash-memory

Context: I'm conducting a research project which involves writing an arbitrary file to **MLC NAND flash memory**, reading it many times to induce read disturb and then observing the disturbance on the rest of the block.

What I need to do:

- Specify the memory location I am writing to/reading from within the memory
- Read the *raw* memory  (avoiding ECC corrections) in order to measure the read disturbance errors

Do you have any suggestions regarding the hardware/software/methodology that I could use to achieve this? ( I am rather new to this area)

Thanks a lot.

Comment: what did the datasheet/documentation for the part and the controller say?

Comment: I have not selected any hardware yet! I am looking for directions regarding the type of hardware/software setup. This is very open scope, I just know it has to be MLC NAND flash (for the particular research I am doing)

Comment: you want to know how to do those things to a flash you need to pick a flash (meaning, read through the various offerings from various companies).  then there is likely a hardware controller built into chips to talk to these flash parts using whatever protocol.  and this is likely not some standard, so specific to each vendors/family implementation.   then you need software to talk to that controller/peripheral.   requests for recommendations is not an SO question.  some of the things you are doing might not be possible, you need to research this first (datasheets, etc)

Comment: ok thank you for the direction. I will investigate the datasheet for specific flash chips.

Comment: I suspect there will be a common interface or some percentage of the features are common and then there may be some chip specific features.  It may be more of a case that you need to pound on the chip with reads to get read disturb.  I had this issue with a spi flash years ago if we read a location or set of locations constantly eventually we would get the wrong data, by placing certain things in flash we could see where the bad values were coming from when the event happend.  the chip vendor didnt believe us at first then months later realized it was their part...

Comment: lower level access to the part was not visible to us, so ymmv may vary.  you can also try to contact the chip vendor they might be friendly or might be offended, but if you dont try you will never know.  and may provide more support on what you can or cant do with the part.

Comment: Yep, the plan is to read is to read from the same location thousands of times to cause read disturb in the rest of the block then measure the results. The tricky part is reading the memory raw, without ECC correcting the bit flips. Sounds like you've had quite the adventure with this stuff! That's a good point, I will keep in mind contacting the vendor is an option. Really appreciate the help (even if my question was quite open ended!)

Comment: that is the thing about this technology is that they put a lot of ecc/edac bits in, I thought i read somewhere that some technology was often/constantly dealing with errors and had a lot of correction bits (never made sense to me).  but to the point you have to see if you can disable ecc/edac at all

Comment: and not sure a vendor would be willing to expose their error rates so might not want to help you disable it if it is not documented

Comment: i think thats a good starting point, i'm going to start investigating datasheets and interrogating vendors!